# Where can I download Lanaguage Packs for Windows?

Tags: windows-server, language-pack

Where can I download Lanaguage Packs for Windows Server?

Comment: You probably want to let people know which version of Windows this is for, as well as if it's just the OS Language Packs/MUIs, or you want them for the apps too (IE, Office, etc). Or finally if all you really want is the language proofing tools (dictionaries, thesaurus, etc).

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Server 2008 Language Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=03831393-EEF7-48A5-A69F-0CE72B883DF2&displaylang=en)

[Windows Server 2003 Language Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=22CFC239-337C-4D81-8354-72593B1C1F43&displaylang=en)